# Android org.androidannotations.annotations error when compiling at Maven

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven

I am compiling maven project in eclipse and I got error at org.androidannotations.annotations error.

Here are the error log

```
[ERROR] /activities/MainActivity.java:[75,1] error: @org.androidannotations.annotations.sharedpreferences.Pref can only be used in a class annotated with @org.androidannotations.annotations.EApplication, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EViewGroup, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EView, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EBean, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EService, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EIntentService, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EReceiver, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EProvider, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EFragment.
[ERROR] /activities/MainActivity.java:[77,1] error: @org.androidannotations.annotations.sharedpreferences.Pref can only be used in a class annotated with @org.androidannotations.annotations.EApplication, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EViewGroup, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EView, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EBean, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EService, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EIntentService, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EReceiver, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EProvider, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EFragment.
[ERROR] /api/BwfApiV3Service.java:[50,1] error: @org.androidannotations.annotations.sharedpreferences.Pref can only be used on an element that extends org.androidannotations.api.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesHelper
[ERROR] /activities/PrivacyActivity.java:[20,1] error: @org.androidannotations.annotations.ViewById can only be used in a class annotated with @org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EViewGroup, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EView, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EBean, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EFragment.
[ERROR] /activities/MainActivity.java:[84,1] error: @org.androidannotations.annotations.ViewById can only be used in a class annotated with @org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EViewGroup, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EView, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EBean, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EFragment.
[ERROR] /activities/MainActivity.java:[86,1] error: @org.androidannotations.annotations.ViewById can only be used in a class annotated with @org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EViewGroup, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EView, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EBean, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EFragment.
[ERROR] /activities/MainActivity.java:[89,1] error: @org.androidannotations.annotations.ViewById can only be used in a class annotated with @org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EViewGroup, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EView, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EBean, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EFragment.
```

and here are the java file

```
import org.androidannotations.annotations.*;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.sharedpreferences.Pref;
import retrofit.RetrofitError;
import timber.log.Timber;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@EActivity(R.layout.act_main)

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private static final Timber LOG = TimberProvider.getInstance();
    private static final String TOP_LEVEL_FRAGMENT = "TOP_LEVEL_FRAGMENT";
    private static final String NON_TOP_LEVEL_FRAGMENT = "NON_TOP_LEVEL_FRAGMENT";

    @App
    BwfApp mApp;
    @Bean
    BwfApiV3Service mApi;

    @Pref
    AppData_ mAppData;
    @Pref
    UserPrefs_ mUserPrefs;
    @SystemService
    InputMethodManager mInputMethodManager;
    @SystemService
    LocationManager mLocationManager;

    @ViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    @ViewById(R.id.cnt_fragment)
    FrameLayout mFragmentContainer;

    @ViewById(R.id.error_popup_view)
    ErrorPopupView mErrorPopupView;
```

I am not sure what is the problem. anyone can help me this problem?

Many thanks.